# Dropbox API on Android: Always asking for permission to link app to Dropbox account

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

We're using the Dropbox Core API to access a users's Dropbox account in our Android app:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android

When the user starts the app for the first time, he sees the following two Dropbox screens:

**Screen 1**:

[image]

**Screen 2**:

[image]

After the first successful authentication, we store the OAuth2 session key in the `SharedPreferences`, and use the key for all subsequent API access.

This seems to work: When the user starts the app the second time, **Screen 1** doesn't appear, so we assume that we have used the session key correctly.

However, Dropbox still displays the second screen, asking the user for permission to link the app to his Dropbox account. No matter how many times the user has given permission to link the app, **Screen 2** is always shown when the app is started.

Any idea what we're doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution:

Instead of always calling

```
_dropboxApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MyActivity.this);
```

we are now checking if the session is already linked:

```
if (!_dropboxApi.getSession().isLinked()) {
    _dropboxApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MyActivity.this);
}
```

Comment: thanks! I was having the same problem and I found this post. This is the perfect solution.